# Proving limits using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition

Tags: analysis

Would this be the proper way to prove a limit of a function using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition?

> Use the definition of limit to show that $\lim_\limits{x\to2}x^2+4x=12$

Let $\epsilon>0$, then there exists $\delta>0$, such that $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $x\neq 2$ if

$$|x-2|<\delta\implies |x^2+4x-12|<\epsilon$$

$$|x^2+4x-12|=|x+6|\cdot|x-2|$$

Let $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}{|x+6|}$, then

$$|f(x)-12|<|x+6|\cdot \delta$$

$$|f(x)-12|<|x+6|\cdot \frac {\epsilon}{|x+6|}$$

$$|f(x)-12|<\epsilon$$

$$\therefore \lim f(x)=12$$

Comment: You have a beautfiul handwriting, but you should post your effort not as a picture.

Comment: @Cornman thank you for the compliment. I just have no knowledge of programming so it would be very messy if I posted it without a picture.

Comment: Michelle - Latex editing is fairly easy, almost next to writing it on paper. As a starter you can refer this link: [Quick Latex Reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: If you write each equation between a pair of `$` symbols (or `$$` before and after to get the equation in the middle of a separate line), and pay attention to what the question looks like in the review window, you can do a lot without knowing much. Another place to start learning the format is https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: I edited it with proper formatting. Be aware, most people won't bother answering your question, unless you show that you put some effort into your post. (I.e. proper latex formatting).

Comment: @MarkPineau thank you for the edit, I really appreciate it! I guess I have to learn proper latex formatting lol...

Comment: Now that it is edited, is this the proper way to solve these types of questions?

Comment: Thank you! May I ask why we restrict delta less than 1?

Comment: Note that $\delta$ should not depend on $x$.

Answer (score 3):

No. Its not correct. $\delta$ cannot depend on $x$. This is one of those $\delta = min \{1, \epsilon /M\}$ problems. Use the fact that if $x \in (1,3)$ then $|x+6| <9 $. In particular, if $|x-2|< 1 $ then $|x+6| < 9$. Sometimes, when you can't factor or uniformly bound a term you have to settle for bounding it near the limit point. This is perfectly fine because all that matters when taking limits is the behavior of the function *near* the limit point anyways. If you set $\delta = min\{1, \epsilon /9\}$ , then $$|x-2| < \delta \implies |x-2||x+6|< \epsilon$$

EDIT:

Btw, the reason that delta cannot depend on x is because you have to find ONE delta that works for EVERY x. Having delta depend on x will give you a different delta for each value of x.

EDIT 2:

In response to your comment. You're welcome. I was crucified on my first analysis test because I was absent the day he went over this. So now I really harp on people when I see them do it. I can virtually guarantee you that your text has some worked examples of this type of problem (never have come across one that doesn't), and also that a question like this will be on the exam. Another way to see this is to pay attention to order of quantifiers.

$$(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in I)\big(0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon\big)$$

$ \\ $

Your approach would require the order to be $(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\forall x \in I)(\exists \delta > 0)$

Getting familiar with quantifiers will help you a lot in this class in both understanding subtle distinctions in definitions (like uniform continuity vs continuity) and in proofs by contradiction.

For example, how would one prove a limit doesn't exist? It's easy to see by using quantifier negation:

$$
\begin{align}
\sim (\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in I)\big(0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon\big) \\
(\exists \epsilon> 0)\sim(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in I)\big(0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon\big) \\
(\exists \epsilon > 0)(\forall \delta > 0)\sim(\forall x \in I)\big(0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon\big) \\
(\exists \epsilon > 0)(\forall \delta > 0)(\exists x \in I)\sim\big(0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon\big) \\
(\exists \epsilon > 0)(\forall \delta > 0)(\exists x \in I)\big(0 < |x-a| < \delta \, \land \, |f(x) - L| \geq \epsilon\big) \\
\end{align}
$$

Thus to show a limit doesn't exist you have to find an $\epsilon$ such that for every $\delta$, one can find an $x$ with the following property

$$|x-a| < \delta \ \text{ but } \ |f(x) - L| \geq \epsilon$$

Comment: @MichelleDrolet yw. I added some more to the post as well.

Comment: My text definitely does have some examples like these and I am positive there will be at least one question similar to this on my final. That's why I want to make sure I'm doing it correctly. So thank you for your help and attention to detail. It really is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

After this step $|f(x)−12|<|x+6|⋅δ$, you want to try to set a bound on $|x+6|$.

We know $|x-2|<\delta$.

$\implies$ $-\delta<x-2<\delta$.

$\implies$ $8-\delta<x+6<8+\delta$.

We also know for obvious reasons, $-8-\delta<8-\delta$.

$\implies -8-\delta<x+6<8+\delta$

$\implies |x+6|<\delta+8$.

This lets us say, $|f(x)−12|<|x+6|⋅δ<(\delta+8)⋅\delta$

We can choose $\delta$ to be whatever we want, to avoid dealing with $\delta^2$, fix $\delta\leq1$.

Now $(\delta+8)⋅\delta\leq9\delta$

So pick $\delta=min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{9}\}$